# getting error while posting on facebook using javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have a app named bit-to-byte and i have changed all the setting for posting on users wall. when i use the app it works perfectly but for the other users it gives a error. i use this code for posting on wall.

```
FB.login(function(){
            FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', {
                message:srci,
                url:imgURL        
            }, function(response){

            if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error occured');
                console.log(response);
            } else {
            alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
            }
});}, {scope: 'publish_actions'});
```

and i am getting this error.

> message: "(#200) Permissions error" type: "OAuthException"

other user can login to the app successfully but while posting they get the error.

Comment: are you sure ask permission publish_action, publish_stream or user_status ??

Comment: no i just asked for 'publish_action'

Comment: ah one more : status_update

Comment: i noticed that when other user login to the app. the app doesnt asked for permission. what can i do now

Comment: In your app setting https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[AppID]/app-details/ 
you can see button [Configure App Center Permissions] click it and add permission your app to ask user. 
if didn't work
you should use [PHP-Facebook] or more to ask permission user.

Comment: Javascript 

FB.login(function(response) 
   {
      if (response.authResponse) 
      {
          FB.api('/me', function(response) 
          {
              user_id = response.id;
          });
      } 
      else 
      {
          alert("error occured during login")
      }
  },{scope: 'permission1,permission2,permission3'});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you it works because the user you're testing it with is probably the admin of the app. For all other users, you need to get your app reviewed, otherwise you can't ask for more than basic permissions. See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_login
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review